# Cucumber, TypeScript, Error: No tests found when running without examples

Tags: typescript, bdd, playwright, cucumberjs

I faced an issue when I removed examples from my test feature file then I've got an error Error: No tests found. Before that It was working without any problems even without using examples. I removed it because I don't need it anymore and I got error Error: No tests found. Do you know what is the issue?
This is my feature file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLbh7.png)

Comment: Change "Scenario Outline" to  "Scenario" . "Scenario" is used for individual, non-parameterized test cases, while "Scenario Outline" is used for parameterized test cases

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)